# How to order by result set in union query in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I want to use order by clause in my last sql query and I have more than 3 union queries. I do not want to order the top 2 union query but I want to use order by clause in my last sql statement.
Currently, getting error

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

```
select 'Total Number of pat' Name, convert(varchar(20), count(id)) Number from table2 where id = 5
union
select 'Total Number of Doc' Name, convert(varchar(20), count(id)) Number from table3
union
select x.usertype, count(distinct userid) cnt
from [dbo].table1 t
cross apply (values (
    case when t.userid like '%[0-9][0-9[0-9]' then 'transition' else 'non transition' end,
    t.userid
)) x(usertype, userid)
where t.date >= dateadd(day,-7, getdate())
group by x.usertype
order by usertype desc
```

Comment: Have you searched for `[tsql] order by union`?

Comment: Aside: Since you are using `group by usertype` it doesn't appear that you will have any duplicate rows. Using [`union all`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than `union` will avoid the processing needed to exclude duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

`order by` is sorting the result of the unions all together however you can introduce a orderIndex column for imlementing the right ordering.

Here the sample:

I've tried to build sample data in the following code.

```
    create table table1(
        userid varchar(100),
        usertype varchar(100),
        date date
    )

    insert into table1(userid, date) values ('Einsmayr', '2020-10-27')
    insert into table1(userid, date) values ('Eins123', '2020-10-27')
    insert into table1(userid, date) values ('Einschmid', '2020-10-27')
    insert into table1(userid, date) values ('Einshuber', '2020-10-27')
    insert into table1(userid, date) values ('Einsreitmayr', '2020-10-27')

    create table table2 (
        Name varchar(100),
        id int
    )
 
    insert into table2(Name, id) values('Zweirich', 5)
    insert into table2(Name, id) values('Zweifel', 6)
 
    create table table3 (
        Name varchar(100),
        id int
    )
 
    insert into table3(Name, id) values('Dreisinger', 17)
    insert into table3(Name, id) values('Dreibert', 18)
```

This allows the following queries:

```
    select usertype, Number
    from (
        select 'Total Number of pat' usertype, convert(varchar(20), count(id)) Number, 1 orderIndex from table2 where id = 5
        union
        select 'Total Number of Doc' Name, convert(varchar(20), count(id)) Number, 2 orderIndex from table3
        union
        select usertype, count(distinct userid) Number, 3 orderIndex
        from (
            select userid,  case when userid like '%[0-9][0-9[0-9]' then 'transition' else 'non transition' end usertype
            from table1
            where date >= dateadd(day,-7, getdate())
        ) x
        group by x.usertype
    ) y
    order by y.orderIndex, y.usertype
```

Find the solution here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac396c48f5dbcb4a53ad40fac70e9236